# Access environment variables from nginx server instead of environment.ts file

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, angular6, docker-container

I am trying to externalize environment variables in my angular 6 application.
I want to place these properties on nginx server and then access them in my application so that these environment variables can be changed without build and may be without even restarting the server.

What I have done till now is added property file to nginx server through my docker file in external folder under /usr/share and added below to nginx.conf file

```
location /external/ {
            alias /usr/share/external/;
            autoindex off;
        }
```

and now I can access this file from http://localhost/external/sample.json

Next I need to remove properties from environment.ts file and get them from server location. I am stuck there where exactly do I need to make this GET request and fetch properties from server before loading the application.

Also anytime properties are changed, would application bounced be required or there is any other way to use updated properties.

Comment: It looks pretty complicated, wouldn't it be better to save your sample.json on a docker volume and make it available to your angular app that way ?

Comment: this is similar to storing sample.json inside assets folder so that it can be changed on server anytime. but how would i replace my local environment.ts file properties with one available on server/assets folder.